Raspberry Pi Camera won't Initlize
I am trying to get the video feed off of my raspberry pi camera on to my laptop or a cloud server. My camera works, all of the packages are up to date, the preview also works but every time run the program it keeps having this error; "ERROR in app: Camera initiation failed: Camera init sequence did not complete" I have tried everything that I can think of and there is something on the html page where the video should go but there's nothing there.
Here's my script:
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
from picamera2 import Picamera2
import cv2
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def initialize_camera():
    try:
        camera = Picamera2()
        config = camera.create_preview_configuration(main={"format": "RGB888", "size": (640, 480)})
        camera.configure(config)
        camera.start()
        time.sleep(2)  # Allow camera to initialize
        return camera
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f"Camera initialization failed: {e}")
        return None

camera = initialize_camera()

def generate_frames():
    while camera:
        try:
            frame = camera.capture_array()
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
        except Exception as e:
            app.logger.error(f"Error capturing frame: {e}")
            break

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)


I have check all of the connections, I made sure all of my packages where up to date (this is a brand new pi 4) and I've been in a circular conversation with chatGPT and nothing works.

I have a similar structure for my python object detection app and had the following error in the logs:
ERROR Camera camera.cpp:685 
Camera in Running state trying acquire() requiring state Available 
Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.

Didn't realize I was calling multiple time the Picamera2 initialization (with each refresh of the page) so the camera was actually busy from the first initialization.
I moved out the Picamera2 initialization (just outside the app.Flask statement) and everything is working fine now.
You seem to initialize that only once, but would give my workaround a try.
